# Theme change by url

Tags: theming

Pretty new to drupal. I will have roughly seven themes and looking for the best way to change themes by url...  xxxx.com/parents = one theme  xxxxx.com/edu be another theme xxxx.com/daily  will be another theme. There will be about 7 different themes all together. What is the best way to way to make this happen.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the following ways.

1. Use the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.

2. Add the following code to your `settings.php`

   ```
    $theme_urls = array(
      array('/admin','garland'), // Drupal already supports admin theme, anyway
      array('/users','fancy_user_theme'),
      array('/forum','forums_theme'),
   );

   foreach ( $theme_urls as $info) {
     if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $info[0]) === 0) {
       $conf['theme_default'] = $info[1];
     }
   }
   ```